# In Cakephp numeric model name convention

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

i have att_2010_masters table.

and Att2010Master model.

but it is not working.

Is naming convention of model is ok ?

and

what can i do to take numeric value in my table name ?

Answer (score 1):

Though not a thorough answer, I believe that the naming conventions would say that your tables should be `att2010_masters`.

I, personally, work on a CakePHP project that has models like `Preapp105dItem`, where the filename is `preapp105d_item.php`, and the database table is named `preapp105d_items`.

I don't believe that Cake puts a separation between the letters/numbers. Think of them as just more lowercase letters on the end of the first group.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you named the model normally, without the numbers and just use the $useTable property in the model.

```
var $useTable = 'att_2010_masters'
```